# Confusion about Java Versions

Tags: java

So I'm trying to get the latest version of Java.  When I run:

java -version

I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

When I run:

javac -version

I get:

```
javac 1.6.0_65
```

Now I've just downloaded and installed JDK 8.  When I go into System Preferences --> Java --> Update, I see:

```
Your system has the recommended vesion of Java.

Java 8 Update 05.
```

I guess I have a few questions:

1) Don't I want the JDK and my version of Java to match up?

2) Why does my Java Control Panel claim I have Java 8, but my work in the terminal (when checking my Java version) says otherwise?

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Does your `PATH` system variable contain the directory where jdk 1.6 is installed?

Comment: This might be a question that is better suited to SuperUser, as you don't indicate the OS it is impossible to answer. In for example Windows it can depend on the `PATH`, on some (all?) Linux distribution you can configure the _preferred_ Java which is then bound to the `java` command, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probably "simple" answer is you have two versions of java installed. On the command line you currently use 1.6. Thus the old one is active. In system preferences you see the version of java 8.

**Windows:**
You can change the version of the command line to java 8. Set PATH environment variable and JAVA_HOME or via windows preferences. I recommend the first one.

**Mac:** `/usr/libexec/java_home` is the starting point for switching java versions on the command line. Check out [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2) to understand how to handle different java versions on the Mac. IMHO [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/674835) is a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

The Java Platform offers both the `JRE` and the `JDK` in order for users to run Java programs. The JRE stands for the Java Runtime Environment, and the JDK stands for the Java Development Kit.

The `JDK` is meant for Java developers - that is, those who build applications/write programs in Java. It contains tools that are needed for Java coding, including `-javac` to compile programs.

The `JRE` is meant for regular users - those who only need to run Java programs on their computer and are not interested in development.

The reason for the discrepancy in your case is because you're looking at the JRE and JDK and trying to compare the two. The current JDK that you have is `Java 8`, whereas the current JRE that you have is `1.6.0_65`. It is problematic that your JRE version does not match your JDK version, but without your `PATH` variable or other information about your install, we can't help you fix your installation.

Comment: Ah, so I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.9.2)

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, if you use the JDK at all, you want the JRE (runtime environment) to come from the JDK (development environment) (a JDK necessarily includes a JRE).

2) Likely your path variable is set so that you invoke Java from your Java 6 installation; you need to find the equivalent for your Java 8 installation and set the path for that.  Without information about your operating system, we can't help you do that.

Comment: Am on Mac OS X 10.9.2.  Thanks again!

Comment: On StackOverflow, you should accept the earliest answer that answered your question, and upvote any that you found helpful.  It's the way people gather reputation on the site, and also helps people know that you will do so on other questions.

Answer (score 1):

**We should know the reason for this**

1. Our OS comes with a predefined (built-in)set of tools and utilities. When we try to execute the command `e.g. cls`  in the Windows command line then it is already present in **system path variable** and os will refer the corresponding binary of `cls` to execute the command.
2. However, when we install any third party tool/software then **path** variable is not updated accordingly.
3. When we install different versions of java on your system then installations go to different directories. E.g. *JDK* installation directory for Windows will be
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`
4. Similarly, *JRE* installation directory for Windows will be JDK installation directory for Windows will be
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161`
5. We need to update the path variable of OS to point to the appropriate directory. If we set the path of JDK then it will execute a binary from JDK bin directory.

**Solution**

- we need to update `JDK` or `JRE` version specific directory location into `PATH` Environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can clear it up for you.

1)Yes, arguably you nearly want this to be true.

2)It could be few things, but most likely that a previous instillation was not properly removed. So one gets called instead of the other.